# How to calculate the gravitational binding energy of a uniform cube of length $L$ and mass $M$?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, potential-energy, integration, estimation

The functional form is known already (as attached). But what is the solution for this integral?

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8F3wa.jpg]

Comment: In the 21st century, go numerically. Or google it, probably somebody in the 19th century has done it analitycally

Comment: I did a Monte-Carlo evaluation of $Q$ and found that it is between -0.941 and -0.942.

Comment: The three integrals over either $\mathbf{x}$ or $\mathbf{y}$ can be done analytically to get the gravitational potential of the cube. See https://arxiv.org/abs/1206.3857. I haven't been able to then integrate this potential over the cube to get the binding energy, but I was able to numerically integrate it and again get -0.941... .

Comment: More accurately, $Q=-0.941156...$.

Comment: @patta which reminds me of somewhat related: [Another way to evaluate the gravitational force from a uniform cube?](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/26537/17869)

Answer (score 3):

The integral can apparently be done exactly and the answer is

$$Q=\frac{2\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2}-1}{5}+\frac{\pi}{3}+\ln{[(\sqrt{2}-1)(2-\sqrt{3})]}=-0.94115632219483008005...,$$

which is consistent with the numerical evaluation that I mentioned doing in my comments on the question.

Source: https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0701215

The value was apparently first derived in 2000 by Skeidov and Skvirsky in this paper:

https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0002496

As an explanation of their evaluation, they unfortunately have only this to say: "After some lengthy interactive session with Mathematica, we get...". I personally am unable to get Mathematica to produce this result, but I have no doubt that it is correct.